# Не выполнять замену строки если не выполняется правило регулярного выражения

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, pandas, re

есть список ссылок и существует список из правил, согласно которым необходимо из этих строк вытащить определенную часть строки, если же правило не подходит, то ничего не отображать

был написан такой код

```
line1='/site/page/same-text'
line2='/same-text/same-text/same-text'
df=pd.DataFrame({'original': [line1, line2]})

df['replace'] = df['original'].apply(lambda x: re.sub(r'(/.{0,})(/page)(/[A-Za-z0-9=_-]+)', r'\1', x)) 
df
```

который возвращает

| original | replace |
| --- | --- |
| /site/page/same-text | /site |
| /same-text/same-text/same-text | /same-text/same-text/same-text |

необходимо, чтобы если правило не подходило, то не отображать ничего в строке

| original | replace |
| --- | --- |
| /site/page/same-text | /site |
| /same-text/same-text/same-text |  |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

потестируйте такой вариант (с приведенным примером работает):

```
df['replace'] = df['original'].str.extract(r'(.*)/page.*')

>>> df
'''
                         original replace
0            /site/page/same-text   /site
1  /same-text/same-text/same-text     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вот так будет работать так, как Вам надо:

```
def replace_function(string: str)->str:
    '''
    Function for searching the matches. Returns empty string or the first match if found.
    '''
    matches = re.match(r'(/.{0,})(/page)(/[A-Za-z0-9=_-]+)', string)
    if matches is not None:
        return matches.groups()[0]

    return ''

df['replace'] = df['original'].apply(replace_function)
```

Не получилось в одну строку с ходу, надо подумать